# how to keep an audit of whats being cached

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

We are now using .net caching extensively through out our application, so much so, that we are now looking to extend onto a separate cache server, and use memcache.

One think that i'm a little concerned with, is how to keep an audit of exactly whats being cached and what isn't.

one option we where considering is to just actually record it in a text file as they are being added.

The other option (although, at the moment, im not too sure of the overhead) is to have a config file. Within this config file, we store the name of the method that we require to be cached, with the cache duration, return type, and cache name. On every call to all methods in the system it will check the config file, if the method exists in this config file, it will cache the result, if not, just continue as normal. This way, we could control the cache on the fly.

These are 2 the options we are considering. Or is there a more robust alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know memecached, but I work with AppFabric Cache from Microsoft (which is by the way nice alternative, take a look at it, if your app is on Microsoft web stack) and there is build in way to monitor cache. You are supposed to create multiple caches, which you can name, set custom expiration and eviction policies etc. Then just run the app and use tooling to monitor number of objects in each cache, and many more preformance indicators.

Do you have any reason why do you need log each object separately (your text log idea)? Isnt it enough to know how many apples and how many oranges do you have, and what is the hit/miss/eviction count and TTL for these types of objects?

Comment: Thank you, i will take a look at AppFabric. Basically we just wanted to have some kind or record of what procedures are cached. We have come across 'outputCacheSettings' within the config settings, so i think we will base it on that, ie rather than setting the duration for the cache when we want something cached, we will simply pass a profile name to a procedure, and the use linq to SQL to retrieve the required information.